# visual studio c++ to C# socket program

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-c++, inter-process-communicat

I am using OpenCV for image processing and so far I have done everything purely on c++. I want to create GUI application using c# however, I am unsure about there communications protocols. Primary reason I want to use C# with C++ is because I am using Kinect SDK and I don't like programming in C++/CLI framework.

Since Kinect libraries are better using with C# I am wondering if I could get some help in developing socket programming for c++ to c# duplex communication. Note: Mostly I will be sending and receiving image data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Googleing 'OpenCV C#' brougth me this library as the first result:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

You don't need any socket communication as long as you don't want to distribute the application to different computers (like GUI on one computer and Image Processing on another).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion and actually your are correct about the socket. Firstly, EMGUcv is not that powerful according to some forums whist OpenCV on the other hand is powerful in almost all aspects. Now the problem with me here is visual studio C++ takes like 7seconds to compute sift descriptors of an image, which is way too long. Ubuntu on my Laptop takes about a second to do that. If i can implement a socket program, I can use GUI on windows and kinect while main processing in Ubuntu system therefore I might achieve almost real time performance. Any suggestion are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: You have to think first about the architecture of your distributed application; especially who will be server and who will be client. Then you should think about the protocol that these two will use to transfer the data. Keep in mind, that with TCP/IP you don't get complete messages, you get parts of the communication stream. So you should have in your protocol some length information or message delimiters. Maybe there are already protocols that match your needs and that are implemented in C# and C++.